# Designing update mechanism for code-database application

Tags: python, design-patterns, updates

I have a python based application that contains a big number of modules
and interacts with two databases:

1. metadata (that needs to be updated on certain occasions)
2. client data
   This application can be deployed manually in an environment without internet access.

**What are the best practices and things to consider when implementing update mechanism for this kind of system?** 
Almost all the information is about the packing and distribution phase - signing and etc, but I'm more concerned about the update process itself.

I thought about handling code updates with pip package versions and the metadata database by script based on its version.
This raise new questions like:

1. How the mechanism should handle code updates that have certain side effects or prerequisite?  For example the schema of a user configuration
   file has been changed - so the previous configurations should be converted to the new one (I guess it should be transparent to the user).
   Obviously this is done only when updating from version X to Y and not on a clean installation (Where the default values can be assigned).

   How it should be handled especially if we have a versions gap? - for example the client version is 1, the latest is 4 
   and the need for conversion is from 2 to 3. It should be a cumulative update that will hold all the updates (1->2->3->4) and handle all this
   with scripts? Or each update should stand by its own and the client should run the series of the updates?
2. In case the metadata database is huge ~GBytes. What is the best way to manage its updates? Obviously not sending to the client every time the whole database - what is the best way to calculate the deltas between two versions and send only a script with DML instructions?
3. How to manage the dependency between the database and the code base versions? for example if a field in the database schema was changed
   so the code base version should be also updated (code version X supports database version Y)?
4. How the fault recovery should be handled in those cases? for example when installing a seriouse of pip package updates
   and one of them fail in the middle? how to recover to previous state? is there a good way to backup the current version besides copying the files?

Answer (score 1):

Well, what you need is a graph. Yeah, a data structure. I bet your graph gonna be directed and acyclic - DAG. And if not, you're most probably got in a trouble.

1. Not sure what are you asking. But there is no version gap. Never. There is a fully-deterministic sequence: v1 -> v2 -> v3 (Wow! Looks like yet another DAG, doesn't it? However this one is the simplest one you will deal with: just a regular linked list!). Once client's app discovers the fact that an update is somewhere there, it asks server for a.. sequence of commands or steps to get from the current version to the latest. Once again, it asks for a graph. Then it does what server told to do.
2. Yeah, compute deltas. Store deltas. By the way, deltas naturally represented as a.. graph. `GIT` is a famous example, right? More than that, quite often it indeed makes sense to change entire architecture to fit this necessity - currently it is commonly referenced as an "event sourcing": the ideas is that you store an initial - never modified - state along with long-long-long sequence of changes which has happened to this state so far. And each time you need an actual state, you ideally use `Google`'s `map/reduce` approach to.. reduce entire changeset into a single change, which trivially applied to the initial state thus producing actual state. It is quite fast, easily testable and, trust me, extremely reliable for a huge systems (as long as data persistence mechanism is there and no changes are lost while travelling via unstable networks, of course).
3. I don't think it is a separate issue. It is a part of deltas-problem. Seems like you're trying to build quite complicated system. There is a rule: no simple deltas will work well for the sophisticated system. Conclusion? First of all, think about your deltas. It is all about them.
4. Well, assuming there is a state transition `version 1 -> version 2`, there might be dual state transition: `version 2 -> version 1`. Just a side note: you can get yet another (directed) graph by "flipping" vertices of an existing one. That's what happens here: there is "forward" graph and produced-by-it "backward" graph. If you'd like more mathematical approach, you need a [group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)). There is a VCS driven by this very idea - [darcs](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Understanding_Darcs/Patch_theory).

Comment: Besides the code issues that can be solved version control alike mechanism, there is also the code peripherals and another dependencies like apt-get packages and etc.
As i understand from you answer, your advice is to implement and to store a delta update code for each edge on the version DAG graph?
Whats the more simple solution ? a re-installable installation that is idempotent?

Comment: @sborpo, well, since all your questions are dancing around the "dependencies" problem, graph is a **only** way to describe those. Idempotent solution indeed might work.. for a while; until your systems grows huge enough or performance issues arise. Then you'll get back to dependencies problems, which will lead you... towards directed acyclic graphs. By the way, as far as I now, `apt-get` is a great example of graphs being used to solve problems of the same kind.

Comment: Hard part - is to compute deltas in a correct, reliable way. It might be challenging to plug such a behavior into existing solution, depending on a source code quality. But once you achieved that, the rest is quite simple: graphs are one of the oldest known structures, it won't be painful to work with them leveraging known frameworks. By the way - there is a nice graph database - `neo4j` - that might fit to store deltas. Then your problem reduces to a deltas computation.